# F1 scores depend on which class is given the positive label?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Does f1 score really depend on which class is given the positive label?

When I use scikit learn's f1 metric, it seems to:

```
>>> from sklearn import metrics as m
>>> m.f1_score([0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1,0])
0.8
>>> m.f1_score([1,1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,1])
0.8571428571428571
```

The only difference between the first and second case is that 0 and 1 have been swapped. But I get a different answer.

This seems really bad. It means that if I'm reporting the f1 score for a cat/dog classifier, the value depends on whether cats or dogs get the positive label.

Is this really true, or did I mess something up?

Comment: Why does this question have 2 votes for closing as "needs details or clarity"? The question is clear, and a [mre] is also included...

Comment: Probably because the problem was not clear in the reviewer's minds. I am not sure, maybe stackoverflow's scoring is encouraging people to close questions. I think there are people that sees a close vote and vote to close straight away. It happened more than once that while I was writing an answer the question was closed.

Comment: In that case the question would have a close vote of someone who got it wrong by any reason, and a second vote of someone who was influenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiclass classification you should use a [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) measure. Cross-Entropy is invariant to relabeling. By relabeling you are only reordering the terms in a summation.

If you want to use f1 score, you have to use F score, be aware that it will be invariant to label swapping if, and only if, the number of true positives equals the number of true negatives.

In your example I see 3 true negatives, 2 true positives. If I remove one true negative, we have the same F1 score after swapping labels.

```py
m.f1_score([1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0]) # 0.8
m.f1_score([0,0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1]) # 0.8
```

##### Mathematically

Let's start with one formula from [Wikipedia F-score page], in order to skip some steps.

[image: F1 = tp/(tp+(fn+fp)/2)]

Were `tp` is for true positive rate, `fn` is false negative rate.
I will use a `'` to denote the measures for swapped labels.

By swapping labels we have `tn'=tp`, `fn'=fp`, `fp'=fn`, `tp'=tn`.

If you want
`F1'=F1`. We have `tp/(tp+(fn+fp)/2)=tp'/(tp'+(fn'+fp')/2)=tn/(tn+(fn+fp)/2)`. That is satisfied if, and only if, `tp=tn`.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I've chosen it as the answer. This makes me like f1 even worse as a measure. Unfortunately, I have to use it. But I also don't see cross-entropy being useful here. Cross-entropy can be arbitrarily high.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, that after the labels are decided, cross-entropy doesn't make too much sense. You are not the first person who I know that expresses this feeling about F-scores.